# length of each line using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to read a CSV file line by line and echo something different if the length of the line is 7999.

I manage to do something as below, which reads each line and checks the number of character for each line, but the issue is that I am getting no value in %result% and `echo(%result%` prints a blank value. Any idea what am I doing wrong here? Thanks

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (REPORTS.csv) do (
    set "line=%%a"
    call :strlen result line
    echo(%result%
    if %result% EQU 7999 (
        echo %%a
        echo(short=%result%
    ) else (
        echo %%a
        echo(long=%result%
    )

    pause
)
:strlen <resultVar> <stringVar>
(
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "s=!%~2!#"
    set "len=0"
    for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
        if "!s:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
            set /a "len+=%%P"
            set "s=!s:~%%P!"
        )
    )
)
( 
    endlocal
    set "%~1=%len%"
    exit /b
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use DelayedExpansion in `if` and `for` loops and take care of the brackets:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (REPORTS.csv) do (
set "line=%%a"
call :strlen result line
echo.!result!
if !result! EQU 7999 (
    echo.%%a
    echo.short=!result!
) else (
    echo.%%a
    echo.long=!result!
)
)
pause 
goto:eof    

:strlen <resultVar> <stringVar>
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "s=!%~2!#"
set "len=0"
for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if "!s:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
        set /a "len+=%%P"
        set "s=!s:~%%P!"
    )
)
endlocal &set "%~1=%len%"
exit /b
```

Your code doesn't ever work in many areas.

Answer (score 1):

Put this section into another subroutine, similar to `:strlen`

```
echo(%result%
if %result% EQU 7999 (
    echo %%a
    echo(short=%result%
) else (
    echo %%a
    echo(long=%result%
)
```

Note also that your main routine will continue into your subroutine when finished, so at end-of-file(reports.csv) the batch will execute `:strlen` one final time and exit through the `EXIT`

I'd recommend adding a

```
GOTO :EOF
```

Immediately before the `:strlen` label. This is understood by the processor to go to end-of-physiacl-file (the colon is **required**)

When a compound statement enclosed in parentheses is to be executed,
the statement is first parsed from the open parenthesis all of the
way to the matching close-parenthesis.

At this time, any `%var%` is replaced by that `var`'s value from the 
environment **AT THE TIME IT IS PARSED** (ie its **PARSE-TIME** value.)

**THEN** if the statement seems valid, it is executed.

There are three common ways of accessing the **RUN-TIME** value of the
variable (as a `FOR` loop executes, for instance.)

1/ `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` which switches to a mode where
!var! may be used to access the runtime value of `var`
2/ `CALL set var2=%%var%%` to set the value of `var2` from the 
runtime value of `var`
3/ Executing a subroutine, internal or external within which `%var%` 
will be the runtime value.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%i IN (1 2 3) DO (
ECHO START of run %%i
ECHO using ^!time^! : !time! - PARSE TIME was %time%
CALL ECHO using CALL %%%%TIME%%%% : %%TIME%%
CALL :report
timeout /t 5
ECHO using ^!time^! : !time!
CALL ECHO using CALL %%%%TIME%%%% : %%TIME%%
CALL :report
ECHO END of run %%i
ECHO.
)
GOTO :eof

:report
ECHO :report says TIME is %TIME%
GOTO :eof
```

A few items to note:

1. The instruction

   IF ERRORLEVEL n echo errorlevel is n OR GREATER

   ***ALWAYS*** interprets the RUN-TIME value of `ERRORLEVEL`
2. `IF SET VAR` ***ALWAYS*** interprets the RUN-TIME value of `VAR`
3. The `magic variables` like ERRORLEVEL and TIME should never
   be SET. If you execute

   SET ERRORLEVEL=dumb

then `ERRORLEVEL` will adopt the value `dumb` because the current
value in the environment takes priority over the system-assigned value.